# problem in installing RGBD Slam

Tags: slam, navigation, rgbd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use Ubuntu 12.04 and  ROS Fuerte. I want to install RGBD slam.I try above commends in my ros package path

> $svn co http://alufr-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/rgbdslam_freiburg  
>  $rosdep update

but while I type this command > rosdep install rgbdslam_freiburg I got these error

> ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
> Missing resource rgbdslam_freiburg
> ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
> ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
> ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/125876/problem-in-installing-rgbd-slam/) by [ghazaleh](https://answers.ros.org/users/11236/ghazaleh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-02-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure your ros workspace is correctly defined. You should not install the rgbdslam package in opt/ros folder.
The instructions on the page are very clear. Make sure your ROS environment and workspace is properly set.
See this page on how to set up your ros workspace [ROS workspace tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment)

---

Originally posted by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) with karma: 340 on 2014-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wilk](https://answers.ros.org/users/7921/wilk/) on 2014-02-04**:
a good idea is if You have created a workspace to add these lines in .basrc file:

1. source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash
2. source ~/fuerte_workspace/setup.bash

If You have created Your workspace and it worked and after some time reseted a computer then You "lose" path and You need to add it again (or bash it :) )